# Como criar uma JTable dinâmica?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Tenho uma `JTable` em meu formulário, queria que o tamanho(numero de linhas e colunas) da tabela sejam de acordo com o numero que o usuário digitar, como fazer em java?

Comment: O que já tentou fazer?

Comment: Ainda nada,não achei nenhuma dica!

Comment: Ai complica, a resposta seria ampla demais, seria bom você postar alguma tentativa, ou o que ja fez até agora, para ter uma base de resposta.

Comment: Apenas o comando para setar o numero de linhas e colunas de uma jtable ja serviria

Comment: A resposta abaixo lhe ajudou? Você pode aceitá-la clicando no `v` ao lado do post :)

Answer (score 2):

É possível criar uma tabela vazia, pois um dos construtores do [**`JTable`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable-int-int-) permite passar o numero de linhas e colunas, e a tabela é internamente criada utilizando o `DefaultTableModel`.

```
int numLinhas = 5;
int numColunas = 3;
JTable table = new JTable(numLinhas, numColunas);
```

O exemplo acima exibe algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apenas lembre-se de passar o `JTable` para um [**`JScrollPane`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html), senão não será exibido o cabeçalho da tabela e, possivelmente, nem os scrolls quando forem necessários.

---

#### Referências:

[How to Use Tables(Oracle)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)